# r : strange function behaviour when sourcing from other script

Tags: r

I have two files svm.R and usefulFunc.R. 
I have written this customized function for feature normalization in 2nd script and calling  it from the 1st script.

here is my function

```
featureNormalize <- function(datax, startCol, endCol, meanSd)
{
  n <- endCol - startCol + 1
  print(n)
  for(x in c(1:n))
  {
    print(x)
    datax[, startCol + x - 1]<- (datax[, startCol + x - 1] - meanSd[x,1])/meanSd[x,2]
    head(datax[, startCol + x -1])
  }
  print('here')
  datax
}
```

when I call this with following code

```
> trainer <- featureNormalize(trainer,1,10, meanSd)
[1] 10
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10
```

It neither prints `head` of `datax` nor the `'here'`outside the for-loop.

when I brought it in the svm.R it worked fine. but it doesn't work from the other script while other functions in that script work fine.
I can't figure out what's going on?

additional info :

```
> dim(trainer)
[1] 12096    13
> meanSd
         mean         std
1  2749.32255  417.678187
2   156.67665  110.085801
3    16.50159    8.453927
4   227.19570  210.075296
5    51.07652   61.239406
6  1714.02321 1325.066358
7   212.70430   30.561287
8   218.96561   22.801966
9   135.09200   45.895189
10 1511.14729 1099.936493
```

Comment: Could you please use `dput(trainer)` and paste the output into your question to provide us with your data for testing?

Comment: Using something like `featureNormalize(matrix(1:100,10),1,10,5)` works for me, e.g. printing `n`, `head()` and `"here"`.

Comment: meanSd is a dataframe

Comment: Any specific reason you are not using base functions  `scale`/`sweep` e.g `apply(mtcars,2,scale)` OR  `fn_standardize <- function(DF) {   meanVal <- apply(DF, 2, mean); sdVal <- apply(DF, 2, sd); rv <- sweep(DF, 2, meanVal,"-") ; rv <- sweep(DF, 2, sdVal, "/") ; return(rv) } ; fn_standardize(mtcars)` and `fn_standardize(mtcars)-apply(mtcars,2,scale))` to verify

Comment: @Osssan well I have partially done that for meanVal and sdVal.  I could use sweep but still like to know what's the issue. Also the reason I am not using the scale is because I am calculating mean and sd over train data and then using it for all 3 i.e. train, cv, test